# Multiclass classification using TensorFlow Quantum

Tags: tensorflow, multiclass-classification, quantum-computing, tensorflow-quantum, cirq

I am running some examples and tests on TensorFlow Quantum (TFQ) and I am struggling to perform a multi-class classification. I will used the MNIST classification example as base (https://www.tensorflow.org/quantum/tutorials/mnist), since this is where I am starting from too.

For binary classification I played with the different examples of classes and different gates combination, and the classification result is obtained by measuring a single readout qubit (qR)result, thus if qR=0 we classify with class 0 and if qR=1 then we have class 1.

I extended it to a multi-class problems, so we have a 4 classes (0,1,2,3). To do this I change the labels of the classes with `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train)`, such that the labels get converted from single values to vectors (0 -> (1,0,0,0); 1-> (0,1,0,0); etc..), use `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalHinge()` as loss of the model and create 4 readouts qubits, one for each class (M(qR0, qR1, qR2, qR3) = (0,0,1,0) -> class 2), and this works.

However, this method increases massively the size of the circuit. So what I want to do is to pass to TFQ only 2 readout qubits and use the combined measurement for the 4 classes classification (|00> = 0, |10> = 1, |01> = 2, |11> = 3). Ideally this would allow a 2^n multi-class classification, where n is the number of qubits. In Cirq I can achieved this output by performing a `cirq.measure(qR0, qR1, key='measure')` on the two readout qubits. However I am struggling in passing such command to TFQ, since from what I understand it measures only the qubits that end with a single qubit Pauli gate.

So, is there something that I am missing in the functionalities of TFQ that allows such kind of measurements in the training process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with this snippet:

```py
bit = cirq.GridQubit(0, 0)
symbols = sympy.symbols('x, y, z')

# !This is important!
ops = [-1.0 * cirq.Z(bit), cirq.X(bit) + 2.0 * cirq.Z(bit)]
# !This is important!

circuit_list = [
    _gen_single_bit_rotation_problem(bit, symbols),
    cirq.Circuit(
        cirq.Z(bit) ** symbols[0],
        cirq.X(bit) ** symbols[1],
        cirq.Z(bit) ** symbols[2]
    ),
    cirq.Circuit(
        cirq.X(bit) ** symbols[0],
        cirq.Z(bit) ** symbols[1],
        cirq.X(bit) ** symbols[2]
    )
]
expectation_layer = tfq.layers.Expectation()
output = expectation_layer(
    circuit_list, symbol_names=symbols, operators = ops)
# Here output[i][j] corresponds to the expectation of all the ops
# in ops w.r.t circuits[i] where keras managed variables are
# placed in the symbols 'x', 'y', 'z'.
tf.shape(output)
```

Which I took from here: https://www.tensorflow.org/quantum/api_docs/python/tfq/layers/Expectation .

The shape of the `output` tensor is `[3, 2]` Where I have 3 different circuits and I took two expectation values over each circuit. The value at `[1, 0]` of `output` would be:

[image: U value 0]

[image]

Then the value at `[2, 1]` of `output` would be:

[image: U value]

[image]

The shape and contents of `output`'s values are partly dictated by the shape and contents of `ops`. If I wanted to make the output shape `[3, 3]` I could just add another valid `cirq.PauliSum` object to the `ops` list. In your case if you want the probability of getting 00, 01, 10, 11, on two particular `cirq.GridQubit`s `q0` and `q1` you can do something like this:

```py
def zero_proj(qubit):
  return (1 + cirq.Z(qubit)) / 2

def one_proj(qubit):
  return (1 - cirq.Z(qubit)) / 2

# ! This is important
ops = [
  zero_proj(q0) * zero_proj(q1),
  zero_proj(q0) * one_proj(q1),
  one_proj(q0) * zero_proj(q1),
  one_proj(q0)* one_proj(q1)
]
# ! This is important
```

Making the output shape of any layer that ingests  `ops`: `[whatever_your_batch_size_is, 4]`. Does this help clear things up ?

Comment: Thank you your answer! Yes it works and it really cleared up some things I didn't understand correctly about TensorFlow Quantum.